# Datatable FixedHeader Plugin Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

**i am using Datatable FixedHeader Plugin. check my code. but plugin not work properly.
console error occured "TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns is not a constructor"
please give me solution. thanks**

$(document).ready(function() {

```
var table=$("#example").dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": false,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "sort": "position",
      "scrollY":"300px",
      "scrollX":"200px",
     "scrollCollapse": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "searchatOrganisations",
        "aoColumns": [

            { "mData": "aoId" },
            { "mData": "aoCreatedby" },
            { "mData": "aoCreatedon" },
            { "mData": "aoModifiedby" },
            { "mData": "aoModifiedon" },
            { "mData": "aoName" },
            {
                "mData": null,
                className: "center",
                defaultContent: '<a href="vieweditatOrganisations?aoId=${aoId}" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
            }
        ]
    } );
 new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table, {
    leftColumns: 1,
    rightColumns: 1
} ); 

} );
```

**TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns is not a constructor**

Answer (score 2):

Include Following JS and CSS to get fixed header in DataTable.

https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.7/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js

ref Link: https://datatables.net/download/release

Answer (score 1):

You need to include JS file on your page.

dataTables.fixedHeader.js

I also faced same problem, this is the js which needs to include